# Excel add spacing to range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I need help making array "Start" show as "Result" with using the argument spacing. If someone knows how to do this seemingly easy thing please help. Thank you!

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWkv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Start" cell is A1, put in C2 and extend :

```
=if(mod(row()-row($C$2),$B$2)=0,index($A$1:$A$4,1+(row()-row($C$2))/$B$2),"")
```